# Start 2 MongoDB connections in Elixir

Tags: mongodb, elixir, erlang-supervisor

I am making an application that needs to connect to 2 mongo databases at the same time.

I am using the mongodb (v0.4) module.

For now my supervisor looks like that:

```
children=[
    worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo, database: "transit", seeds: ["localhost:27017"], pool: DBConnection.Pool]])
]
opts= [strategy: :one_for_one, name: HugoEtl.Supervisor]
Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

I would like to open another connection at the same time to pump data from one connection to the other.

How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What may prevent one from opening 2 connections in parallel naively would be the automatic Ids of workers corresponding to the equivalent module name.

```
children=[
    worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo, database: "transit", seeds: ["localhost:27017"], pool: DBConnection.Pool]]), 
    worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo_final, database: "final", seeds: ["localhost:27017"], pool: DBConnection.Pool]], id: MongoFinal)
]
opts= [strategy: :one_for_one, name: HugoEtl.Supervisor]
Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

This will start 2 database connections, you can query each with:

```
# first connection 
Mongo.find(:mongo,"collection",%{})
# second connection 
Mongo.find(:mongo_final,"collection",%{})
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that really helped